# Python: returning the next greatest integer from a list when variable is in the list

Tags: python, list

I'm writing a program to filter through coordinates and determine whether or not the coordinate is a safe position based on random data and changing data. If the y-position is already in the list, I am currently incrementing by one and moving to the next position.

I was wondering for example you have:

```
a = [1,3,5,6,2]
y = 2
```

Is there a way to return the next largest integer not in the list. For example in the above it would return 4. If so would this prove to be faster than incrementing by one each time. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: requirement not clear. Can you explain the relation between a, y and the returned value 4 in your example?

Comment: How much preprocessing can you afford to do on the list? Is it part of the “changing data”? What kind of performance are you seeing right now (with which code, exactly?) and what would be acceptable?

Comment: If you were trying to get the maximum number which is missing in the list in between the max and min values, you can do something like max(list(set(range(min(a), max(a))) - set(a))). Pythonic enough for a comment? :D

Comment: Can you post your "incrementing by one" code? Good code could do that with `O(n)` work, bad code might involve `O(n²)` work (though if `a` is always smallish, the "bad" code might be fine; small `n` and a low constant multiplier can make `O(n²)` outperform `O(n)` with a high constant multiplier after all).

Comment: @NimeshkaSrimal: No need for the `list` call; just let `max` iterate the resulting `set` directly (also, you want `min`, not `max`, and you need to adjust your `range` to start at `y`, since they want a value equal to or greater than `y`). My one-liner (after imports) would be `import itertools`, `next(itertools.dropwhile(set(a).__contains__, itertools.count(y)))` which only needs to do a linear scan of `a` once; it's basically the naive incrementing loop, but pushed to the C layer, and with a single pass of `a` to start to convert to `set` for `O(1)` membership testing.

Comment: For example, the list is defined as a and y would be holding the current y position. If the y position is already in the list I am trying to move to the next largest integer that is not in the list, or else I would add y to the list and continue until reaching the bounds. Based on performance, my current program is acceptable i'm just curious to whether this idea of skipping to the next largest integer rather than incrementing by one would prove to be faster.

Comment: And “continue”… with some other value of y? Do you have a list of ys?

Comment: @joevenez: If you're not suffering performance issues at all, I'd stick with what you've got. Optimize when your program is too slow, and profiling shows a particular part of the code is responsible for most of the slowdown.

Comment: @Ryan right it would continue until all y values are populated in the list based on the size of the grid defined by the user at the beginning of the program. For example 4x4 grid would have 4 y values. The grid is NxN and I am using variables x and y to for the coordinates. So my thought process was once a column(x) was filled instead of setting y to 0 and increment by one each time when moving to the next column, find the next largest integer not in the list to skip over locations already used and possibly cut down on time. Y values cannot be used more than once.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks for the advice. I appreciate it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you sort the list, you can use a binary search to get the answer quickly. The `bisect_right` function will return the index of the number you seek, or `len(a)` if the number is `>=` the largest in the list.

```
>>> a.sort()
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6]
>>> import bisect
>>> bisect.bisect_right(a, 2)
2
>>> bisect.bisect_right(a, 4)
3
>>> bisect.bisect_right(a, 7)
5
```